# SwiftUI: make view B have same width of view A as A changes ratio?

Tags: swift, swiftui

this the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var r:CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            Color.red
                .aspectRatio(r, contentMode: .fit)
            HStack {
                Text("LEFT")
                Spacer()
                Text("Right")
            }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

It simply draws something like this:

[image]

I want the HStack to follow the width `Color.red` has as I set the ratio of `Color.red`.

So, the ratio of `Color.red` can change and I want the HStack to have the exact same width of `Color.red`

As r changes, how can I make the width of the HStack match the width of `Color.red` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the size of `Color.red` using `GeometryReader` and pass it back up the hierarchy using a `PreferenceKey`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var r:CGFloat = 1
    @State private var redWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            Color.red
                .aspectRatio(r, contentMode: .fit)
                .readSize { redWidth = $0.width }
            HStack {
                Text("LEFT")
                Spacer()
                Text("Right")
            }
            .frame(width: redWidth, height: 40)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
        
    }
}

extension View {
  func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    background(
      GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
        Color.clear
          .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
      }
    )
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
  }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

See https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/

Answer (score 1):

If the height of the bottom content is fixed then an easy way to achieve this layout is to use padding to reserve space for the `HStack` below the red square. Then the `HStack` can be shown as an overlay in this space. This way, you don't even need the `VStack`:

```swift
var body: some View {

    Color.red
        .aspectRatio(r, contentMode: .fit)
        .padding(.bottom, 40)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            HStack {
                Text("LEFT")
                Spacer()
                Text("Right")
            }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
}
```

If the height of the bottom content is not known then instead of padding, you can use a hidden version of the content (or in fact, any content that has the same height) to reserve the space. For example:

```swift
private func bottomContent(withSpacer: Bool) -> some View {
    HStack {
        Text("LEFT")
        if withSpacer {
            Spacer()
        }
        Text("Right")
    }
    .frame(height: 40)
    .background(Color.blue)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.red
            .aspectRatio(r, contentMode: .fit)
        bottomContent(withSpacer: false)
            .hidden()
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        bottomContent(withSpacer: true)
    }
}
```